# Преобразование данных ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Имеется код:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train',
    target_size=(32, 32),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')
val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'val',
    target_size=(32, 32),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(
     train_generator,
     steps_per_epoch=3000// 32,
     epochs=3,
     validation_data=val_generator,
     validation_steps=1500// 32)
```

И он хорошо работает, но для моей задачи требуется изначально плоская нейронная сеть(Все нейроны сети должны быть типа Dense), подскажите как это реализовать. Прошу не кидать камнями с нейронными сетями я на вы)

Comment: можете пояснить этот момент: `"но для моей задачи требуется изначально плоская нейронная сеть"`? Почему? Для чего? Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: @MaxU Сеть запускается на raspberry pi которая и так загружена под завязку, и хотелось бы как-нибудь уменьшить нагрузку.

Comment: Серьезно??? Простые полносвязные нейронные сети обычно дают плохой результат для классификации изображений. Именно поэтому придумали сверточные нейронные сети, глубокое обучение и т.д.

Comment: @MaxU на самом деле дело даже не в самой архитектуре сколько в эффективности данная конфигурация не работает для моей задачи. Имеется датасет:https://goo.gl/qd6oNQ и обученная мной нейронная сеть наотрез отказывается распознавать первые три класса изображений. Раньше я использовал плоские сети на C++ и они хорошо справлялись. Какую бы конфигурацию вы бы мне посоветовали?

Comment: я в ответе уже объяснил почему данная архитектура не будет нормально работать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В указанной в вопросе архитектуре несовместимые параметры:

```
model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))   #  <---- здесь бы подошла функция 'softmax'
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', ...)
```

Функция активации `sigmoid` используется только для *бинарной* классификации - т.е. такой, у которой на последнем скрытом слое используется *один* нейрон и в качестве функции потери используют `binary_crossentropy`:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', ...)
```

Если же у вас мультиклассовая задача, т.е. присутствует более двух классов классификации, то в качестве функции активации используют `softmax`, а в качестве функции потери используют `categorical_crossentropy`:

```
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', ...)
```